# How can i debug php scripts in pdt when i use a virtual host?

Tags: debugging, eclipse-pdt

I'm using apache rewrite modules, and adding a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\fuel\public"
  ServerName fuel.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and then add .htaccess file rewrite all to index.php

I also set pdt debugging environment using a new php server configured as follows:

- Server Name : `fuel.local`
- Base Url: `http://fuel.local`
- Local web root: `D:\wamp\www\fuel\public\`
- And choose file: `/fuel/public/index.php`

But when I start debug, the url generates like this:

`http//fuel.local/fuel/public/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=13365326777529`

However, I want the url like this:

`http//fuel.local/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=13365326777529`

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

When using eclipse-php2, there's a chekbox to not auto generate the url.

I'm using eclipse-php-3.0.2.v2011102768-Win32

Answer (score 0):

I found myself having the same prob so I discovered that what you need hidden due an annoying bug in PDT plugin

**Create a new Debug Configuration**

- Open Eclipse
- Select the Run > Debug Configurations… menu option
- Double click the PHP Web Page option
- Set the following fields
- Name: $domain
- PHP Server: $domain
- File: Browse to the file belonging to this domain that you wish to debug
- Breakpoint > Break at First Line: Uncheck this if you do not wish to break at the first line in the file
- URL > Auto Generate: Uncheck if necessary (ending / in first checkbox and beggining / in second checkbox is OK)   ----- this one is missing and is exactly what you need.. try ZendStudio trial
- Click the Apply button
- Click the Close button

I hope this will be fixed in 23 of Jun 2012 with the new pdt plugin.